# Trouble with kubectl: Connection Refused Error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, localhost, amazon-eks, kubectl

I'm encountering an issue with kubectl that I've been struggling to resolve. When I attempt to run kubectl version, I consistently receive the error message "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Here's some context about my setup:

I'm trying to connect to a Kubernetes cluster hosted on AWS EKS.
I've verified that my ~/.kube/config file contains the correct server URL, certificate authority data, and context for the cluster.
Despite double-checking my configuration and trying various troubleshooting steps, such as manually testing the connection with curl and running kubectl commands with verbose output, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before or have any insights into what might be causing this error? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions for troubleshooting steps to try next.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without more information. Generally, that error means, "you don't have a configuration file", but maybe there are other situations that can trigger it. Can you show us the output of `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config current-context`?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the wrong configuration.

*After the error happens*, it's better to check `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config current-context` to ensure your `kubectl` points to the correct config. I recommend you also run `which kubectl` to ensure you use system `kubectl` and not, e.g., Minikube's kubectl or any other wonderwaffles' `kubectl` that usually explicitly comes with installation.

If the above doesn't work, again, *after the error happens*, run `KUBE_CONFIG=.kube/config kubectl get nodes` to override whatever configuration you have to see what's happening.

Lastly, if everything doesn't work, run `kubectl -v7 get nodes | grep "Config loaded from file"` to see what config it's reading in logs. Line's example:

```
I0209 18:48:32.576938   17140 loader.go:374] Config loaded from file:  /Users/m_muravyev/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Muravyev Maxim**,

I wanted to thank you for your assistance with the Kubernetes configuration issue I encountered. Your guidance was incredibly helpful, and I wanted to provide some feedback on the steps you suggested.

First, I followed your advice to check the current configuration using `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config current-context`. Unfortunately, it seems that there were no contexts configured, and the current context was not set. This helped me realize that the issue might be related to the configuration itself.

Next, I verified the `kubectl` executable location using `which kubectl`, and it confirmed that I was using the system kubectl binary located at `/usr/local/bin/kubectl`. This reassured me that there were no issues with the binary itself.

Regarding overriding the configuration using `KUBE_CONFIG=.kube/config kubectl get nodes`, I encountered connection refused errors, indicating a deeper issue with the Kubernetes API server or configuration.

Despite not resolving the issue immediately, your guidance helped me narrow down the problem and better understand the Kubernetes configuration and troubleshooting process.

In the end, I managed to resolve the issue by locating the kubeconfig file at `/home/ec2-user/.kube/config` and using it with the `kubectl` command via the `--kubeconfig` flag. This allowed me to successfully retrieve information about the nodes in the Kubernetes cluster.

Once again, thank you for your support and guidance. Your assistance was instrumental in helping me navigate through this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to share a quick solution I found for the "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused" error in Kubernetes:

Switch to the root user:

```
sudo -i
```

Disable swap:

```
swapoff -a
```

Exit from the root user:

```
exit
```

Try running `kubectl get nodes` again.
Check `kubectl version`